# Approval Azure Pipeline with Rest API

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on an azure devops pipeline and am wanting to approve the pipeline. I read up on the steps I need to do which is to first get the approvals list with [Approvals - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) then I need to approve it with [Approvals - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) in the body use the `approvalId` received in the query step.

I am doing this in nodejs and was looking at this repository [azure-devops-node-api](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api) but I do not see an implementation for approvals. Does anyone know where I can find the nodejs implementation for Approvals?

Comment: Seems like there [isn't a support](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues/471) for Approvals yet in the azure-devops-node-api. Why not call the Azure DevOps REST API directly from your custom nodejs client?

Comment: That's unfortunate, thanks for telling me. Will that allow me still do the Approvals operations though? @Sibtain

Comment: Yes it shouldn't be a problem if you use the native REST API from Azure DevOps in your nodejs code.

Comment: @Sibtain Whenever I make the query rest api call directly in postman I don't get a list of pending approvals like it says it will return. I get a list of everything in the pipeline. How do I filter those pending pipelines? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP